# Spring boot insert whole file in a transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a to read and insert data in two CSV files. Each CSV represent a category of data. the data in CSV is not delta but a whole snapshot. Example on file is for temporary employees and other one is for permanent employees. if there is error in the temporary employe data CSV nothing in database should change.
Currently i have the step defined as below. The inserts inside the chuck size are transactional. Example if the chunk size is 50 and if there is error in the 50 row currently being processed all of them will be rolled back.

```
  @Bean
        public Job dBatchJob(final JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, final Step dBatchStep)
        {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get(BATCH_JOB_NAME).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .listener(listener).flow(dBatchStep).end().build();
        }
  
@Bean
    public Step dBatchStep(final ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<DPrice> classifierCompositeItemWriter)
    {
    stepBuilderFactory.get(BATCH_STEP_NAME).
                        .<DPrice, DPrice> chunk(chunkSize).reader(multiResourceItemReader()).processor(processor())
                        .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter)
              .listener(dSkipListener).listener(dRetryListener).listener(dStepListener).build();
    }
```

How to make all the rows in CSV part of one transaction not just the ones part of chunk